# What is this sea shell?

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology, molluscs

Found in Belgrade, possibly carried back from the Mediterranean or Aegean coast.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not /Bolma rugosa/, but in fact [/Angaria delphinus/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angaria_delphinus), from the Indo-Pacific.

Listing on [gastropods.com](http://www.gastropods.com/7/Shell_277.shtml)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! You are more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. (Answers must also be self-sufficient, not just links.) Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion and instead should be a comment on another answer. ——— Please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site. Thank you! 

Comment: This ID seems accurate. The species varies a lot and it's often like the one from the OP.